# can’t remove background on leaf texture

Tags: texturing

i was watching a tutorial on making a realistic forest today. When I got to the leaves on the trees *(made with the sapling generator)* i couldn’t figure out how to remove the background so that the leaf texture was just the leaf.

The tutorial is slightly out dated and he had something on the shading tab that i don’t.

anyone have a solution?

Comment: Hello and welcome.  Can you [edit] your question to include more details?  Does your image texture have transparency, for example?  A screenshot would be welcome

Comment: if you are in eevee....check whether in material settings you have set the mode to alpha blend or hashed

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.